# Issue with calculating a probability with the standard normal table

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(6, 2)$, we are asked to calculate $P(X \leq 10)$. My professor taught me that

$$
F_Y(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \Phi(x),
$$

for $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. This implies two crucial facts:

$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}F_Y(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\Phi(x), \quad \text{and} \quad P(a < Y < b) = \Phi(b) - \Phi(a).
$$

(To loosen up the formalism here, $a$ and $b$ here can also be $-\infty$ and $\infty$, meaning appopriate limits.)

Now we calculate, with transforming $X$ into a random variable $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$:

\begin{align*}
P(X \leq 10) &= P(-\infty < X \leq 10) = P(-\infty < X < 10) = P(-\infty < Z < \frac{10 - 6}{2}) \\
&= P(-\infty < Z < 2) \\
&=\Phi(2) - \lim_{x\to-\infty}\Phi(x) = 0.9772 + 0.5 = 1.4772,
\end{align*}

which is a contradiction, since a probability measure cannot exceed $1$.

Here is also the professor's manuscript:

[image]

As you can see, he input an incorrect value for $\Phi(2)$, but got the overall correct result, as $P(-\infty < Z \leq 2)$ is indeed $0.9772$.

Please, help me find out where the logical error in the calculation happens, and whether I understand the professor's calculation correctly. (He used the formulas I listed above when solving other exercises as well.) Thank you.

Comment: If $\Phi(x)$ is the function that computes the area from $-\infty$ to $x$, then $\Phi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty.$

Comment: your teacher is confused or something similar. $\Phi(-\infty)  = 0$, because $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F_{X}(x) = 0$. And $\Phi(2) = 0.9772499$

Comment: @daniel So you would call into question the equation $F_Y(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \Phi(x)$?

Comment: Some people normalize $\Phi(x)$ to have limits $0$ and $1$ at $\mp\infty$; others normalize $\Phi(x)$ to have limits $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$. I suspect that's the issue here. Note that the two answers in the OP differ by exactly $\frac12$.

Comment: @GregMartin What does that work for? Where can I read about it? I didn't know that way

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. It was due to a *very* specific and unlikely (fitting, given that we are talking about probability, lol) error in the table for $\Phi(z)$.

In my context, $\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{2} + F_Y(z)$ is true, because it is defined as

[image]

It just so happens that the table has an error at exactly $z = 2.00$. It should be $0.4772$, but is $0.9772$ instead. Taking the correct table value into account returns the correct result. I would like to thank everyone who took their time to help me with this.

Here is the table with the error:

[image]